# Eclipse throws the error "Data cannot be resolved to a type" for using the Project Lombok

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, lombok

I am new to Java and Project Lombok, I am trying to follow some tutorials to understand it better. I have created a very simple java project to test the Project Lombok and it throws the error `Data cannot be resolved to a type` when I add the `annotation` `@Data` to my class.

I am using macOS and Eclipse IDE for running my Java application. Following are the steps that I followed to run my first Java and Lombok project:

1. Downloaded the latest Project Lombok version 1.18.16 and placed it in the Documents folder.
2. Installed the Project Lombok in my system using the command `java -jar lombok.jar`.
3. Restarted my Eclipse and verified that Project Lombok installed in the Eclipse -> About Eclipse: "Lombok v1.18.16 "Envious Ferret" is installed. [https://projectlombok.org/"](https://projectlombok.org/%22)
4. Created a new Java project and the class `Alien`.
5. Added the Project Lombok JAR to my project Classpath.
6. Added the `@Data` annotation to my `Alien` class and imported the JAR file but I get the error `The type lombok.Data is not accessible` for my import statement `import lombok.Data;`
7. Also, I get the error `Data cannot be resolved to a type` for my annotation at the class level `public @Data class Alien`

I am really unsure what's wrong. I tried to find out but all the answers have mentioned the same steps. I was just wondering what am doing wrong. Any help would be really appreciated.

Following is my complete code:

```
package com.lamboktest;

import lombok.Data;

public @Data class Alien {
    private int age;
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: I guess you have a `module-info.java` file in the default package but without the required `requires` statement. If yes, does deleting the `module-info.java` file fix your issue?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the issue. I remove the file and it worked. Just out of curiosity why was this file created by default? Because I did not create this file and it was created with the Java project. Please add your answer, I will mark as correct.

Comment: When you create a Java project there is a dialog asking to create `module-info.java` file you have probably clicked the _Create_ button instead of the _Don't create_ button. I closed this question as duplicate even thought the title mentions that a type cannot be resolved, but on the import statement I guess you have a "not accessible" error, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer as it maybe useful for somebody in the future.

As mentioned in the comment removed/deleted the file `module-info.java` which was created by default during the project creation. Everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The error `The type SOMETYPE is not accessible` is... bizarre. As far as I know, there are only three ways to get that error:

1. `lombok.Data` isn't public. Except, it is, so this can't be it.
2. You've manually added a list of forbidden packages ('access rules') in eclipse, to deny yourself access to lombok. Presumably, you'd remember if you did that, so it can't be this.
3. lombok is loaded as a module, and the `lombok` package isn't exported. Except, the only versions of lombok that exist either aren't modularized (and module-info-less jar files export everything), or they are, and the `lombok` package is exported. So it can't be this.

Perhaps it would be useful to doublecheck all of these:

1. I guess `javap -cp lombok.jar lombok.Data`, and check that it's public, but, this just cannot be it, so you probably don't need to bother.
2. For that access rules thing, which is the most likely of 3 very unlikely options, go into your project's setup (right click on it in e.g. the package explorer, and pick 'properties...', you can set up lots of stuff from there), go to 'build path', find the lombok.jar, open it up, and check 'access rules'. It should read 'no rules defined'.
3. Go into your project's setup and ensure it's all set to java8, and rebuild. Presumably you want to use new features, but the point is to at least isolate down to: It's a module issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I followed the steps you mentioned and the following are my observations. 1. The methods are public in Lombok `public interface lombok.Data ...`. 2. For the JAR file it says `Access Rules (No Resrictions)`. Although I see one more entry which says `is Not Modular` is this fine? 3. I am currently using the JAVASE-14 (JRE [14.0.2]). So as per your results I guess everything seems to be fine but I am still getting the error. Is there anything which I can try?

Comment: 'Not modular' is good. I'm out of ideas as to how this could be. One last thing to try is to ensure that you are not a module, or, if you are, that your module-info lists 'requires lombok;' or what not. You can set the 'language level' to 8 even if you don't have a JRE8 involved, which guarantees modules aren't involved (java8 didn't have them yet). Do this in the properties... page when you right click on the project.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response and help. Actually the issue was with the file `module-info.java` which I removed and everything is working as expected now. Thansk again.